# Why does this Microsoft Access Report hang when trying to export?

Tags: sql, pdf, report, sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

I have a pretty simple report created in Microsoft Access.  The report data pulls from 2 Custom SharePoint lists plus the UserInfo table - that's why the field names are long.  Whenever I Run the SQL, it returns results very quickly-seemingly correct results.  However, whenever I go back to the Report View and attempt to *Print it to PDF* or *Export it to PDF*, it hangs.  CPU pegs at 25%, (which I think is full usage of one core) and Memory usage just grows and grows.  I let it run for about 2 hours tonight while I was doing other things, but it did not complete.  This has really been a pain, when it shouldn't be.

I've tried setting both to be INNER JOINS, but no luck.  Also, if I limit the results by adding a **WHERE** clause, I can sometimes get it to print results.  If I use ID's that do not have any records in the 2nd table **[Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form]**, it will return results quickly.  But if I limit it to even a single result that contains entries in both tables, exporting/printing will never complete.

Here's the SQL being used:

```
SELECT [Innovation Challenge].ID AS [Innovation Challenge_ID], 
[Innovation Challenge].[Create a name for your idea:], 
[Innovation Challenge].[Primary contact for your idea:], 
[Innovation Challenge].[Primary contact's group:], 
[Innovation Challenge].[Challenge question:], 
[Innovation Challenge].[Months to roll out:], 
[Innovation Challenge].[Idea Description ("What?")], 
[Innovation Challenge].[Reasons for Pursuit ("Why?")], 
[Innovation Challenge].[Notes:], 
[Innovation Challenge].[Coach you worked with:], 
[Innovation Challenge].[Do you want to be put in touch with other groups?], 
[Innovation Challenge].[If yes, please list the groups and explain:], 
[Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form].ID AS [Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form_ID],
[Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form].[What resources and capabilities do you need to implement your id], 
[Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form].[How much funding do you estimate you would need to develop and i], 
[Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form].[How confident are you in the likelihood of success?], 
[Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form].[Please provide rationale for your assessment of the likelihood o], 
[Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form].[Are there any significant risks (e#g#, operational, health, safe], 
[Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form].[If yes, please describe the potential risks:], 
[Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form].[What is the high-level impact?], 
[Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form].[Additional comments/notes, if needed:], 
[Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form].[Coach you worked with:], 
[Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form].[Is this submission complete?], 
[In
```

novation Challenge Final Entry Form].RegistrationID, 
    UserInfo.Name AS [Innovation Challenge_Name], 
    UserInfo.ID, 
    [Innovation Challenge].Attachments, 
    [Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form].Attachments AS [Attachments_Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form]
    FROM ([Innovation Challenge] LEFT JOIN [Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form] ON [Innovation Challenge].[ID] = [Innovation Challenge Final Entry Form].[RegistrationID]) 
    INNER JOIN UserInfo ON [Innovation Challenge].[Primary contact for your idea:] = UserInfo.[ID];

Any help is greatly appreciated!  I'm out of ideas!  Immediate help will be appreciated even more so :-)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Microsoft Access does not work well with Bullet points.  A lot of the data included bullet points.  I can print out items that have none, but it hangs on items that include bullet points.